# Unsure of await functionallity

Tags: python, async-await, discord.py

I am using discordpy to write a discord bot. When calling an external function from an async function, I am receiving an error telling me I am missing a parameter 'ctx' from my function. I believe I have to use the 'await' method, however, I am unsure where.

```
def fromRebootMethod():
    return "Hello"

@client.command()
async def fromReboot(ctx):
    message = await fromRebootMethod()
    print(message)
    await ctx.send(message)
```

This is the error I am receiving:

> TypeError: fromReboot() missing 1 required positional argument: 'ctx'

Comment: `fromRebootMethod()` isn't asynchronous, so you don't need to use `await`.

Comment: Please post the full traceback.

Comment: Thank you, a bit new to asynchronous programming so I appreciate the help.

Comment: The error message says `fromReboot()`, the code you posted calls `fromRebootMethod()`.

Comment: The error has nothing to do with async/await. It says that the function takes an argument that you're not supplying. Show the code that calls `fromReboot()`.

Comment: You're getting an error saying that `fromReboot`, the callback for the command itself, is missing arguments. We can't really do much without the full traceback. `fromRebootMethod` is not async though, so you should call that normally. The default discord.py error handler should print the entire traceback, if not try `traceback.print_exc`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think the provided code sample is completely accurate. Therefore, I am recommending two steps to potentially resolve your issue:

1. Only use `await` when calling a function that is defined with the `async` keyword in the function definition.
2. Take another look at the `fromRebootMethod`'s function definition. It most likely requires a `ctx` parameter which is why your interpreter is asking for it.

Regardless, we need to see the traceback and real code sample.

Comment: If questions are missing details, you should not be answering them - you should ask the OP to edit these into the post. Answers like these *will not be useful to anyone*, except maybe the OP. See [how to answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer) for more information.

Comment: @TheFungusAmongUs Thank you for that advice. How should we proceed here? Should I delete my answer?

Comment: It's up to you, really. You might get downvoted, or maybe you won't - I really just left that comment as advice for the future. I would recommend to flag as Needs Debugging Details and let the 3000+ rep folks sort it out. I would personally delete the answer, and wait until the question is closed/has details edited in.